# не работает тег hasAnyRole()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Суть такая: для сайта нужно ограничить видимость колонки в таблице - сделать видимой только для ролей 'MOD', 'ADMIN', 'SUPER_ADMIN'. Сейчас проверил и перестали работать даже такие команды hasRole('ADMIN').
Но, если я пытаюсь добавить несколько ролей через тот же hasAnyRole('MOD', 'ADMIN', 'SUPER_ADMIN') или же hasRole('MOD') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN'), то ничего не выходит, просто при авторизации не появляется этих столбцов.

**Вот пример как я пытался сделать через hasRole() or hasRole()**

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Author </th>
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Read </th>
        <th sec:authorize access="hasRole('MOD') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')"> Delete </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!--<tr th:if="${news.empty}">
        <td colspan="2"> No News Available </td>
    </tr>-->
    <tr th:each="news : ${news}">
        <td><span th:text="${news.news_id}"> ID </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${news.author_id}"> Author </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${news.tittle}"> Tittle </span></td>
        <td><a href="id.html" th:href="@{http://localhost:8080/news/{id}(id = ${news.news_id})}"> Read </a></td>
        <td sec:authorize access="hasRole('MOD') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')"><form action="news/delete" method="post"> <!--{id}(id = ${news.news_id})-->
            <input type="hidden" name="news_id" th:value="${news.news_id}" />
            <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

У меня теперь не работает даже hasRole('ADMIN').

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вместо `<th sec:authorize access="hasRole('MOD') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')"> Delete </th>` должно быть `<sec:authorize access="hasRole('MOD') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')">
<th> Delete </th> </sec:authorize>`, взял [отсюда](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-secure-view-layer-using-taglibs/)

Comment: Простите, видимо я не уточнил - я использую не jsp, а thymeleaf